# preg_match doesn't work with REQUEST value

Tags: php, regex, request

I have a simple HTML form with 2 fields, name and email.

I'm trying to prevent users from submitting invalid names. The only characters allowed are:

- letters
- spaces
- these special characters: àäçéèïöü

I get the name using a php $_REQUEST variable and store it in `$name`.

My preg_match is the following `preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z àäçéèïöü]+$/", $name)`.
When I test it in my php code, it works.
But when I test it upon my $_REQUEST variable, it doesn't (though it's displayed correctly in the browser).

For example, if my $_REQUEST variable contains "Jeremy", it works, but if it contains "Jérémy", it doesn't.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show the actual code?

Comment: Have you tried using `utf8_encode($name)`?

Comment: @vcampitelli That was quick. Thanks! I should have guessed it was an encoding issue...

Answer (score 0):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

Have you tried using utf8_encode($name)? –  vcampitelli